# Fetch new key on JWT Signature Validation

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

To give some context, I am trying to verify a JWT signature using Public Key. The public key expires after some amount of hrs which could change. Now the problem is that if the validation fails, I don't know if it failed because of an invalid Token, or the Public Key got expired.

To solve this, I am doing the following:

- Fetch a new key from some URL when there is a validation error
- Use the updated key to validate the token
- If it still fails, then the JWT validation fails

***Code***

I have a HTTP Handler inside which a new instance of `tokenValidator` is created and then `validate()` is called on it.
`keystore` that is used to create the `tokenValidator` is initialized outside the handler

```
type tokenValidator struct {
    keyStore         *keystore.KeyStore
}


func (t *tokenValidator) validate(){
        // get token
        .....
        // validate token
        var err error
        err = t.validateSignature(token, publicKeyName)
        if err != nil {
            t.keyStore.UpdateKeys()  // fetch new keys and try again
            err = t.validateSignature(token, publicKeyName)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("pf token signature validation failed: %w", err)
            }
        }
}
```

***Keystore***

Now, I don't want all the failed validation requests to fetch the key from the URL instead I want to use the updated key for all the requests waiting to acquire the lock.
So, for example, if there are 100 parallel requests, I want the request that acquires lock to update the key. All the others should use the updated key.

```
type KeyStore struct {
    Keys         jwks.JWKPublicKeys  // map[string]rsa.PublicKey
    mu                           sync.Mutex
    isKeyUpdated                 bool
}


func (k *KeyStore) UpdateKeys() error {
    k.isKeyUpdated  = false
    k.mu.Lock()
    defer k.mu.Unlock()
    var err error
    if !k.isKeyUpdated {
        keysMap, err := retrieveKeysFromURL()
        if err == nil {
            k.Keys = *keysMap // update the Keys Map
            k.isKeyUpdated  = true
        }
    }
    return err
}
```

I am new to concurrency-related topics and was wondering if this could be improved. Or if there is some other better solution to this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Assuming you use the popular github.com/golang-jwt/jwt package, [the error returned by Parse](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4#ValidationError) can be inspected to figure out why verification failed. Also, if signing keys rotate regularly, the JWT header _should_ include a [`kid` field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517#section-4.5) that identifies the signing key and is used to detect key rotation before validation. Have you checked if that field exists? That being said, the golang.org/x/sync/singleflight package can help you prevent concurrent key updates.

Answer (score 0):

The idea that you reload keys when token validation fails is a big security risk. Someone can bombard your API with invalid keys to launch a DoS attack by forcing you to reload keys in a never-ending loop. Ideally, you should find a way to determine if a key has expired or not.

You can keep a cache using:

```
cache map[string]*Key
```

where

```
type Key struct {
   once sync.Once
   key rsa.PublicKey
}
```

When you expire a key, you can simply do:

```
cache.cache[id]=&Key{}
```

which will insert an empty key in the cache. To get the key value from the cache:

```
func GetPublicKey(id string) rsa.PublicKey {
   cache.Lock()
   k:=cache.cache[id]
   if k==nil {
     cache.cache[id]=&Key{}
   }
   cache.Unlock()
   k.once.Do(func() {
      k.key=loadPublicKey()
   })
   return k.key
}
```

This way, everybody will wait until one of the goroutines initializes the key.

Comment: right, I was thinking of using rate limiter for my API to reduce the changes of DoS attack.

Comment: Rate is not the problem here, the assumption that auth failure is due to key expiration is. Public keys are usually long lived, and when expired, all tokens generated with its private key will also be invalid, so it sounds odd that they expire after a few hours. Are you sure you are not dealing with expiring JWTs?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to make this assumption (that the key has expired) since I do not have any other way of figuring out what exactly caused the failure (token or key)

Comment: You can actually check the token expiration date

Comment: I am checking all those things like issuer, exp time, etc before validating the token. The validation can still fail even when all these checks are good, isn't it? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If the token has not expired and validation still fails, then the most likely cause is that token is invalid, not that the public key expired. Token should have the public key id in it, you can check if the public key ID matches the public key you cached. But as I said, public keys are quite long lived, they don't expire often. The issue here is that you are trusting the invalid token instead of trusting the key owners. So, it would be easy to launch an attack.